# Having Issue Adding Site to Local Host Virtual Host

Tags: wamp, wampserver, wamp64

Using WampServer 2.4.41 on Win64 Apache I am using this setting in my `httpd-vhosts.conf`bust this is adding the `maper` as a new `VirtualHost` to the WampServer instead of adding it as `Site` into localhost:8080 `VirtualHost`

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#webematics
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName maper
  ServerAlias maper
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/maper"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/maper/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have the `hosts` as

```
#
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

127.0.0.1 maper
```

As you can see the `maper` is listing on my projects but it is not click able and also I am getting this message

> To use them as an http link, you must declare them as VirtualHost

[image]

What am I missing, and how can I fix this to put everything under one Virtual Host `localhost`?

Comment: What you have done is CORRECT. What do you think the problem is

Comment: You dont need to use port 8080, you are not adding any real security. As you are using `Require local` even if your router let connections into your network, they would be rejected by Apache. And 8080 is such a regular used alternative its adding nothing other than hassle as you have to add `:8080` to your URL to get to the site

Comment: The message you highlight is just informational, not an error

Comment: But this is adding a new VirtualHost to the Server instead of adding new site

Comment: A new VirtualHost is a NEW SITE. Hosting companies use this all the time to pack 100 sites onto one Apache